# How do I delete these post types in my WordPress database?

Tags: database

I have two post types from an old template I'd like to delete but I can't figure out where to remove them. I thought I saw them in MySQL database but I can't locate them again to remove them.

[image]

Comment: That isn't coming from the DB.  A plugin or your theme are registering the post types with `register_post_type()`  https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/register_post_type/

Comment: Yes, actually I just found it seconds before I saw your reply! I'm using the Total theme and I found the boxes I needed to uncheck to remove them. Thanks!